# If a cell within the row contains "new" return date from the date row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Goal to return the date (which is the column heading) when the cell contains "new" so as to get the customer start date associated with the unique customer number.

My first column has unique customer IDs. The columns after which have dates starting `8/1/2017 to 4/1/2019`. The row contains customer activity "new","contraction","expansion" for each customer.

[image]

I was filtering the column for new and copy pasting for that date. This is highly inefficient.

Example: For customer#102309 the start date should be 6/1/2018 as that is when the cell value contains "new".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to tell without looking at your actual sheet to see how the data is stored, could you post a screenshot?

Try an `INDEX` & `MATCH`:

For each row, you would have something like:
`=INDEX($A$1:$Z$100,1,MATCH("new",$A2:$Z2))`

Where `A1:Z100` is your full range of data, and `A2:Z2` is the full width of whatever row you're inputting the formula on.  That should copy down and return the result you're after.

Comment: apologies, i have added screenshot

Comment: I just had a followup on this. If there are two instances of "new" in a row because a customer left and reactivated at a later period. Can there be logic built to get both of dates?